# Unable to start Program 'http://localhost:3137/'. an operation is not legal in the current state

Tags: c#

when I am running my project on chrome this error raised!

when I change the browser to **microsoft edge** this problem solve, but another problem raised that, on Mircosoft edge when I want to make some changes in **_layout.cshtml** file the window reboot automaticly.